# htaccess rewrite for simplified url structure causing infinite redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm making a very small project, whereas normally I would use a PHP framework that handles this for me, I don't want the unneeded clutter of a framework. I have this structure:

```
-> assets
   -> css/etc
-> pages
   -> api.htm
   -> scramble.htm
   -> unscramble.htm
-> structure
   -> header.htm
   -> footer.htm
-> index.php
```

All of these files are in a directory themselves, `example.com/example/scrambling/`

So, to access my files, normally I would have to access `example.com/example/scrambing/pages/api.htm` for example - but I want all of the page loading to be handled through index.php.

My goal is to access the file above by simply going to `example.com/example/scrambling/api`

I found some questions on how to achieve this with .htaccess, but none of them are working for me. They always result in an infinite loop, and getting redirected to `/example/scrambling/pages/index/pages/index/pages/index/pages/...` - I'm not really sure how to go about solving this issue.

My current .htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?f=$1
```

and I try to access the page name by `echo $_REQUEST['f'];`

How can I make the .htaccess file not infinitely redirect me?

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will definitely work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```